# String Comparison with Equal and Almost Equals in Vb.Net or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

i have a string. For example `'Hamam Soap 50g'` . and i have a dictionary collection with two columns `(Product Name, Product Code)`. I want to search a particular product in dictionary collections if the product match , i need to get the product code for that matching product..

```
  Product Name              Product code

  Hamam Soap 100 gram       123433
  Medimix Soap 50 g         942488
  Hamam Soap 50 gram        954878
```

My sample dictionary collections shown above.. I need to get the product code. for that particular product `'Hamam Soap 50g'`. but the difficulty here is the string which i want to compare with dictionary may be differ in some characters.. so i need to get almost matching product and its code.. can anyone help me how to write matching algorithm or is there any method available to get required code.

I am using Vb.Net..

Comment: what do you mean by **may be differ in some characters**

Comment: Almost equals is a "fuzzy" search.

Comment: anyway you can use one of "fuzzy" string search shown [here](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=fuzzystring)

Comment: You can use levenshtein algorthim https://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein to done this.

Comment: @styx Yes. it may differ in some characters..